How to transform an integro-differential equation into weak form for FEM
I have the following 2D boundary-value problem which I would like to solve numerically using FEM software:
\begin{equation}
a(x,y)\nabla^2 u(x,y) + \int\int K(x,y,x',y')u(x',y') dx' dy' = f(x,y),
\end{equation}
subject to the boundary conditions $u_{\partial\Omega} = h(x,y)$ where $\partial\Omega$ denotes the boundary of an arbitrarily shaped 2D domain $\Omega$. Also consider that the domain $\Omega$ may have holes in it (multiply-connected domain). Assume that all functions are scalar and continuously smooth, but $K(x,y,x',y')$ is singular at $x=x'$ and $y=y'$.
I am not sure how to transform this into weak form because of the convolution integral in the middle. Is there a way to deal with it?
EDIT: Let's simplify the problem further by assuming a(x,y)=1.

Are you sure the first term $a(x,y)\nabla^2 u(x,y)$ as opposed to $-\nabla( a(x,y)\nabla u(x,y) )$ ? That looks like another non-standard difficulty since it prevents easy integration by parts. But perhaps that is indeed an additional difficulty in your PDE.

Noting that the convolution integral is just a function of $u$, $G(x,y,u) = \iint K(x,y,x',y')u(x',y') dx' dy' $ and assuming that $a(x,y) \ne 0$, the equation can be written in the form
$$
\nabla^2 u(x,y)=\underbrace{\frac{f(x,y)-G(x,y,u)}{a(x,y)}}_{ = H(x,y,u)}
$$
If we want to handle the convolution as an external force, which keeps the system matrices sparse, we can use, for instance, Picard iterations: starting from some initial approximation $u^0$, solve $\nabla^2 u^{n+1} = H(x,y,u^n) $, whose weak form would be something like
$$
-\iint_{\Omega} \nabla u^{n+1} \cdot \nabla v \,dx\,dy= \iint_{\Omega} H(x,y,u^n) v \,dx\,dy.
$$
Depending on the boundary conditions, there can be an extra term coming from green's formula. Also, you must be able to (numerically) compute values of $H$ on the mesh points.

Why linearize at all? The problem is already linear. You also don’t address the fundamental problem of how to formalize a convolution in a finite element framework

@whpowell96 You are correct, the problem is linear. The point here is to come up with an approach that makes the problem treatable with standard finite element software. The possibility of introducing a forcing term, externally calculated, is normally available, while the possibility of adding the convolution part to the system matrix is most likely not available (at this point we would need to know the precise software we are talking about).

Here is something rather basic:
You want to find out how the equation interacts with the integration against a test function. That could be called the underlying idea of weak formulations to begin with.
So we multiply against a test function $v(x,y)$ and integrate:
\begin{equation}
    \iint a(x,y)\nabla^2 u(x,y) v(x,y) dx dy + \iint \iint K(x,y,x',y')u(x',y') v(x,y) dx' dy' dx dy  = \iint f(x,y) v(x,y) dx dy,
\end{equation}
That is the most basic first step.
Building on that, you will might want to modify the term involving derivatives. That is independent of the convolution term.
If you prepare a finite element method, keep in mind that the matrix corresponding to the convolution term will generally not be sparse.
